# NextJS local images vs CDN images

Tags: next.js, web-applications, cdn

What is the ideal way to host images inside a NextJS repo? Is it better to serve from a CDN link or put images directly in local and import and use it.?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the type of images and your use-case.

**For static and relatively small images (ex: company logo, landing page images) I suggest using NextJS Image functionality.** NextJS will do optimization for these images like changing the format and loading them lazily.

**For bigger images and user uploaded content (ex: Discover page on Instagram) I suggest using a CDN.** This might even be the only option because using NextJS for this use-case will require you to have a server that can store all of these images. You can also use the cloud loader option NextJS provides ([Reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader-configuration)) to optimize these images.